# Beta reduction of Lambda Calculus

Tags: math, lambda, lambda-calculus

I have the following lambda calculus:

1) λx . katze(x)(Garfield)

2) λP . λx . P(x)(tea)

3) λy . λx . likes(x, y)(Mia)

How do I reduce them with the Beta Reduction?

My solutions:

1) katze (Garfield)

2) tea

3) likes(Mia)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When performing beta reduction, you substitute the bound variable to the lambda function with the value supplied. The notation for that is `[param := value]` and you pick up the first variable that is given.

In the case
`λx . katze(x)(Garfield)` -> `katze (Garfield)` the reduction is correct. We've substituted the `x` variable for `Garfield` and removed `λx` in the process leaving just the expression inside. Here are the steps that would be taken:

`λx . katze(x)(Garfield)`

= `katze(x)[x := Garfield]`

= `katze(Garfield)`

However, the other two are not correct. You are forgetting that you have a lambda function where the expression inside is another lambda function. Since you have a *single* input, you only have to reduce *one* function - the first one, leaving the other. You can think of it of peeling off the outer one and exposing the inner.

In the case of `λP . λx . P(x)(tea)` this can be better represented as `(λP . (λx . P(x)))(tea)` where now each lambda function is surrounded by brackets. Since we supply a single input `tea`, we only resolve the outer function with parameter `P` (leaving the brackets for some clarity):

`(λP . (λx . P(x)))(tea)`

= `(λx . P(x))[P := tea]`

= `(λx . P(x))`

= `λx . tea(x)`

Or without the brackets:

`λP . λx . P(x)(tea)`

= `λx . P(x)[P := tea]`

= `λx . tea(x)`

As for the final function, it still has the same problem that you are removing both functions, when only one input is given. The correct reduction steps are:

`λy . λx . likes(x, y)(Mia)`

= `λx . likes(x, y)[y := Mia]`

= `λx . likes(x, Mia)`

Comment: Thanks. Now I can perform the Beta-Reduction for myself.