# Beta reduction Lambda calculus example

Tags: lambda-calculus

(λw. w) (λu. λv. u) (λu. λv. v) (λu. λv. u)

Can anyone give me a step by step Beta reduction of this example?
I'm really confused

Comment: What part are you stuck on? How far can you get by yourself? Do you know how to beta-reduce anything? Do you know what alpha conversion is?

Comment: [Does this example help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59841496/)

Answer (score 3):

`(λw. w) (λu. λv. u) (λu. λv. v) (λu. λv. u)`

Apply (λw. w) to (λu. λv. u). As this is the identity function, nothing changes.

`(λu. λv. u) (λu. λv. v) (λu. λv. u)`

Apply (λu. λv. u) to (λu. λv. v). It is substituted for u in the expression. Since we now might get confused by the multiple v's in our first expression, we can alpha rename the v's in the inner expression to another variable, x.

`(λv. (λu. λx. x)) (λu. λv. u)`

Apply (λv. (λu. λx. x)) to (λu. λv. u). Since v does not appear in the lambda's body, the argument is effectively discarded.

`(λu. λx. x)`

We can now (optionally) alpha rename again to restore the original variable names.

`(λu. λv. v)`